# caxlsx / axlsx Pivot Table on separate sheet

Tags: axlsx

I am trying to follow this example:

https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/blob/master/examples/pivot_table_example.md

This code works fine in my existing workbook export.

I am trying to add a pivot table to my existing data on another sheet:

[image]

```
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Expenditures") do |sheet|
  ...  
end
   
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Pivot Table") do |sheet|
  
   sheet.add_pivot_table 'M4:M4', 'Expenditures!A1:L100' do |pivot_table|
       pivot_table.rows = ['Vendor', ID]
       pivot_table.columns = ['Month']
       pivot_table.data = [ref: 'Amount', num_fmt: 4]
       pivot_table.pages = ['Year']
  end
    
end
```

Except it throws this error:

```
undefined method `row' for nil:NilClass
```

If I add this to the same sheet it works fine.  Can you not reference another sheet for pivot tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set `data_sheet` in the block or use the `PivotTable.new` constructor directly. Here's what it looks like to do it by setting `data_sheet`:

```rb
expenditures_sheet = wb.add_worksheet(name: "Expenditures") do |sheet|
  # Code to populate the expenditures sheet
end

sheet.add_pivot_table 'M4:M4', 'A1:L100' do |pivot_table|
  pivot_table.data_sheet = expenditures_sheet
  pivot_table.rows = ['Vendor', 'ID']
  pivot_table.columns = ['Month']
  pivot_table.data = [ref: 'Amount', num_fmt: 4]
  pivot_table.pages = ['Year']
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mike - one question as I am unclear on how to implement this.  How / where do I set that reference?  I tried `expenditures_sheet = sheet` in my expenditure `add_worksheet` block but it throws an error when I try to call `sheet.add_pivot_table` in the new second sheet just for the pivot table.

Comment: I updated my code in the question to be more clear on how I am implementing this.

Comment: and for the same sheet?

Comment: @DanTappin sorry I just saw your follow-up question. I'm assuming you either worked this out or not, but I've updated my response to show how you would reference the expenditures sheet in the block that constructs the sheet with your pivot table.