# caxlsx / axlsx Pivot Table on same sheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, pivot-table, xlsx, caxlsx

I'm trying to do the same as that question
[caxlsx / axlsx Pivot Table on separate sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532764/caxlsx-axlsx-pivot-table-on-separate-sheet)
but in the same sheet.

When i do:

```
summary_sheet.add_pivot_table 'A91:E140', 'A53:O68' do |pivot_table|
  pivot_table.rows = ['Activity']
  pivot_table.columns = ['Project']
end
```

And then go to inspect what happened, i find that the source data on the generated file have `$'DPCache_Data Sheet'.$A$1:$O$16` while i been waiting `$Summary.$A53$O68`

And yes, don't return what i want, giving pivot_table.data_sheet to itself with something like

```
pivot_table.data_sheet = summary_sheet
```

or this

```
pivot_table.data_sheet = pivot_table
```

not works anyway.

UPDATE FOR @kevinluo201

Your reply do that
[image]

Thank you but not solves.

My file starts with

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
```

Doing with

```
wb = Axlsx::Package.new.workbook
```

Return an empty file

Comment: Where do you want your pivot_table to be inserted at? And what is the range of data you want to analyze by pivot data?
btw, I think you don't need `pivot_table.data_sheet = summary_sheet` if you want the results to be shown on the same sheet.

Answer (score 0):

`:add_pivot_table` can be used as `add_pivot_table(:pivot_table_position, :data_source)`

If you want to create a worksheet called "Summary" and insert data and then create a pivot table, here my version I modified a little bit from the https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/blob/master/examples/pivot_table_example.md

```rb
require 'caxlsx'

p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook

wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Summary') do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ['Activity', 'Project']

  # Generate some data here in the range of 'A53:O68'
  # ...
  # ...
  # ...

  # within the same worksheet, call :add_pivot_table
  sheet.add_pivot_table '$G$5', 'A53:O68', sort_on_headers: ['Activities'] do |pivot_table|
    pivot_table.rows = ['Activities]
    pivot_table.columns = ['Project']
  end
end

p.serialize 'pivot_table_example.xlsx'
```

Open the generated `pivot_table_example.xlsx` and go to `G5` cell, you'll see the pivot table there with the data source from 'A53:O68'.

Comment: Your solution just added the pivot table at the beginning, without data anyway. I will update the question with a capture replying to you.

Comment: I was using caxlsx-3.3.0. Did you use the same version?

Comment: From the Gemfile.lock, version is axlsx (1.3.6)